# I installed node through nvm-windows but the command 'node-v' does not exist

Tags: node.js, nvm-windows

I installed node through nvm-windows but the command 'node-v' does not exist，
I did command 'nvm use 18.12.1'， That tips is “Now using node v18.12.1”. It means i had installed successed ?

I expect node to install successfully.

Comment: The command is not `node-v` it is `node` and you pass the argument `-v` to the command. So you type it like this: `node -v`

Answer (score 2):

Just to check, did you try ***node-v***? If yes, you miss the space.

The right command should be `node -v` or `node --version`.

Comment: I try node -v ,but the result is same